# Issue in getting size of File in android

Tags: android, file, outputstream, fileinputstream

This Code is not working for me.

```
long length = file.length();
length = length/1024;
```

Is there any another method to get size of file?

Comment: `Is there any another method to get size of file??` - SO doesn't work this way. You can't just collect all ways here. `This Code is not working for me..` how exactly? does it crash? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

`File file =new File("//data/data/Your-Application-Package-Name/File/your-file-name"); double bytes = file.length(); double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024); double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);Log.d("file size","size of file in KB:"+kilobytes); Log.d("file size","size of file in MB:"+megabytes);`

Comment: this matches the way used in question. It is not *the other way*